# Master/Detail DataSnap via FireDac and MySql ¿Why data written into a detail record in one client is not seen from a second client?

Tags: mysql, delphi, master-detail, datasnap, firedac

I have a `DataSnap Server` with two `TFDQuery's` via `TFDConnection`to a `MySQL` database.
This querys are in a `master/detail relationship` via a `TDataSource` (neested datasets).  This data is exported via one `TDataSetProvider`.

In the client side, I have a `TDataModule` with one `TSQLConnection`, one `TDSProviderConnection` and two `TClientDataSet's`, one for the `Master` and the other for the  `Neested Detail` via `DataSetField` property.

When i test my client everything works fine.

The problem is when `two clients` are working `simultaneously` over the **same detail record**, the data I write to one Detail in one Client is not seen from my second Client, and vice versa.

Suppose we have this scenario with a simple bill/items relationship:
*Bill1, Item1, OriginalData*

if i read *Bill1* in both clients, both read the same data.
If i modify the *OriginalData* to *ModifiedData* in my First Client, and execute `ApplyUpdates`, it works fine, but then i **refresh** the same *Bill1* in my second Client, and still reading the unchanged *OriginalData*

If I write data into the `MasterTable` everything works fine, buy with my `DetailTable` it seems to get data from some cache or something. I reproduce all via `BDE` components and `Paradox` database and have no problems, but we need to use `FireDac` and `MySQL`

So, here is the question... ¿Why the data written to detail record in the first client is not seen from my second client after calling refresh with `DataSnap` via `FireDac`and `MySql`?

I'm using Delphi Xe5 update 2.

Note: The `Master/Detail` is a `parametrized Query`, so only one Bill is active at a time.

Once again, sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by setting **`FetchOptions.DetailOptimize=FALSE`** of the `TFDConnection` on the server side.

When DetailOptimize is true (default on FireDac) FireDac refresh the detail dataset only when the current detail dataset key field values are different from the master dataset key field values.

For more info read
 [FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.DetailOptimize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.DetailOptimize)